# Javascript + build a dynamic variable name from a variable name and string

Tags: javascript, string, variables, concatenation

I'm not clear on the correct syntax to do the following.

- I have tried eval() I have tried [] and {[]} as well..

I start with this:

```
var player1InitStart = 0;
var player2InitStart = 0;
var player3InitStart = 0;
var player4InitStart = 0;

var playerID =  event.target.id; // will return, player1, 2, 3, 4
```

To be used in a check like so:

```
if(eval(playerID + "InitString") == 0){
    //do something, first time starting video
    eval(playerID + "InitString") = 1;
    alert('First Time Playing Video' + eval(playerID + "InitString"));
}
```

I am trying to use the playerID value together with the string: "InitStart"..

so I can then update the target xxInitStart variable above.

How can I concatenate the var playerID with the string InitStart so I can now target one of the playerXInitSTart variables to update it?

Update:  answer/solution that worked for me-

- no clue why the $ character is being used?  (reminds me of PHP)
- no clue why the back tick marks '`' are there either? '`'

  var playerID =  event.target.getIframe().id;
  var targetInitID = `${playerID}InitStart`;

  //access (get or set)
  alert(window[targetInitID]);
  window[targetInitID] = 1;

Comment: Don't. Use an object (or array) instead of 4 separate variables

Comment: Can you put that into some context?  What exactly would I be putting into an array?

I still need to take the returned value/variable (playerID, which will be player1, player2, player 3 or player4).. and tack on the InitStart string/extension to target a variable..   I'm failing to see how an array comes into play here? or helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here we build string and address window[yourvar] to increment, does this work for you

```js
var player1InitStart = 0;
var player2InitStart = 0;
var player3InitStart = 0;
var player4InitStart = 0;

//var playerID =  event.target.id; // will return, player1, 2, 3, 4

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', clickEvent);
});

function clickEvent(event) {
  let playerID = `${event.target.id}InitStart`;
  window[playerID] += 1;
  logVars();
}

function logVars() {
  console.log(player1InitStart);
  console.log(player2InitStart);
  console.log(player3InitStart);
  console.log(player4InitStart);
}
```

```html
<div id="player1">1</div>
<div id="player2">2</div>
<div id="player3">3</div>
<div id="player4">4</div>
```

Here is a solution that follows CertainPerformance advice:

```js
var players = {
  player1InitStart: 0,
  player2InitStart: 0,
  player3InitStart: 0,
  player4InitStart: 0
};

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  div.addEventListener('click', clickEvent);
});

function clickEvent(event) {
  let playerID = `${event.target.id}InitStart`;
  players[playerID] += 1;
  logVars();
}

function logVars() {
  for(let k in players) {
    console.log(players[k]);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="player1">1</div>
<div id="player2">2</div>
<div id="player3">3</div>
<div id="player4">4</div>
```

Comment: while this should work, sometimes we need to not answer the direct question and instead steer OP towards a better approach. This is one of those times.

Comment: Why & where does 'window' come from?

Also where does the 'let' do in the code above?

Comment: @whispers: if this javascript runs in a browser, the browser exposes global variable `window`

Comment: per @SergioTulentsev I agree the second solution, using an object is better. Even better would be an array of player objects.

Comment: I am just trying to set/update a variable to show that is has been played once.
Why are there back ticks on the line that is concatenating the two pieces of data? I see no reason to put those variables in an array.. there will never be any looping going on to update them.

Comment: It builds the correct variable name. If you only need 0 || 1 get rid of my += 1. Here is docs on string interpolation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: While I still have no clue why there are '`' (back tick) characters used.. nor the $ character...  it seems to work.. this was all I needed here:

var playerID =  event.target.getIframe().id;
var targetInitID = `${playerID}InitStart`;

//access (get or set)
alert(window[targetInitID]);
window[targetInitID] = 1;

Comment: @whispers: today you don't need looping, tomorrow you do. Array is a handy data structure that can be useful in many scenarios.

Comment: I use arrays all the time.. but talking about arrays when I'm asking about concatenation syntax seems to bring one in a totally different direction.  Even using an array.. I see no benefit here?  I still would need to concatenate to target my desired variable.

Comment: Whispers the back tick method is a nice clean way of building up string values that contain variables. Especially useful for templating. Worth a read. Happy coding

Comment: @whispers: "I still would need to concatenate to target my desired variable." - not if you don't _have_ variables. No variables - no concatenation. Instead, fetch a simple integer from the dom element and access array by that integer. Something like `players[event.target.dataset.playerid] = 1` Where `players` is a simple array of integers.